# How to identify and click this span in java with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[image]

I can't get xpath of this html as it gives me error and the test case gives failure

I tried by class name of it's outer div or button

```
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait (ChromeBroswerObject, 5);
        WebElement element2 = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/section[2]/div/div[1]/a/p[1]")));
        element2.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Link pls if u can, then I can create xpath.

Comment: https://www.bestbuy.ca

- Login [With already existing account]
- Add any number of items into Shopping Cart
- Follow all the needed steps to finish Payment Operation "Check Out" (except last step) [May be you need to view Shopping cart first to do Checkout]
- Sign Out . this what should i do and the question is a part of it

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're trying to click, but here is my best guess:

css selector:

```
p.offerCta_Bis60
```

Xpath:

```
//p[@class='offerCta_Bis60']
```

If that's the correct element, but the `class` attribute changes on you, you could try this xpath:

```
//p and ./span[text()= 'Shop Now']
```

For a specific product, you can add text for that, for example this would turn the second example into this:

```
//a[contains(p/text(), 'Epic sound for epic study sessions.')]/p and ./span[text()= 'Shop Now']
```

Explanation:

You should identify some attribute you can rely on that will uniquely identify the element, preferably using an `id` or `class`.

In the second example, I'm scanning the entire document(`//`) looking for a `p` node that also has a child(`./`) `span` with the text `Shop Now`.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to click on all shop now links, then try this,

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p/span[contains(.,'Shop now')]"));
for(WebElement link : links)
        {
            link.click();
        }
```

Or if you like just the first shop now link,

```
WebElement element2 = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Epic sound for epic study sessions.')]/p/span[contains(.,'Shop now')]")));
        element2.click();
```

Comment: I used List and it didn't give me error but it didn't work also and nothing happened or clicked

Comment: Whats the size of the list? >0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below xpath.

Make sure to replace `x` with the desired item number.

```
(//section[@data-automation='dynamic-content-offer-list']//div[contains(@class,'ItemsPerRow')])[x]
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

If you want to get all the items in the list and then iterate through them then you can use below xpath with `findElements`.

```
//section[@data-automation='dynamic-content-offer-list']//div[contains(@class,'ItemsPerRow')]
```

If you want to get the `paragraph` under link, then simply extend the xpath as below.

```
(//section[@data-automation='dynamic-content-offer-list']//div[contains(@class,'ItemsPerRow')]/a/p)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Shop now** as the element is a dynamic element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ta[href*='epic-sound-for-epic-study-sessions'] p[class^='offerCta_']>span"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'epic-sound-for-epic-study-sessions')]//p[starts-with(@class, 'offer')]/span[text()='Shop now']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. First locate the parent [`<p>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) preferably by partial text using XPath [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function
2. Then locate [following-sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) (next node having the same parent)
3. And finally filter the resulting [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) by its text

   ```
   //p[contains(text(), 'Save up to')]/following-sibling::p/span[text()='Shop now']
   ```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: You're not using the XPath I provided

Comment: I used it and gaved me the same error all of them the same error